# MS Access Date Serial Function

Tags: ms-access

I just learned about the MS Access date serial function. I saw it used in a query so I wanted to know what it did

I ran

```
select DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())+2,1)-1
```

The date I ran this on is 6/9/2019(mm-dd-yy)

I was expecting 07/31/2018

But I get 7/31/2019

Why is 1 not being subtracted from the year part?

Comment: Because you're not subtracting a year. You're subtracting a day. Why would you think `-1` would subtract an entire year? If you want the previous year, use `Year(Date()) - 1` instead.

Comment: If it is substracting from 365 days why is month being substracted?

Comment: I have no idea what that means. There is no *month being substracted* (subtracted) in either the code or your text.

Comment: Sorry I understand now